# My user is experiencing cut off text but I am not - Can't replicate

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework, text-formatting, winforms

Shifting over from a post on SO which was closed for being insufficiently technical.

I am writing a .NET Windows app using Winforms in VB.NET Framework 4.7.2 on Visual Studio. One user has reported that the text in the buttons on the main menu (he has not gotten to other forms yet) is too large and is getting cut off.  I am trying to fix the issue but I cannot replicate the problem!

[image: User's Button Text cut off]   [image: Button Text as intended]

On the left is what the user is seeing. on the right is what I'm seeing. He has reported that his display is set to 1920x1080, the same as my display setting. I suspected Windows Easy Access setting differences in text size - I changed those to 160% on my computer but the buttons on my app don't change. The text for other apps does increase.  I've also changed "Make everything bigger" Windows setting and it increased the text font and the button proportionally in my test app, meaning I could still not replicate the user's issue.

Button specs: Each button is set to 154x95 pixels. The font is set to Calibri, 15.75pt, style=Bold. The form itself has AutoScaleMode=Font (fwiw, not sure if this has an impact)

I'm not sure what else to try to replicate the issue or what to even ask the user to check on his machine. I *know* something is broken but I am tearing my hair out trying to figure out what. What could cause this issue so I can check it?

Comment: Possibly a browser add-on?  I have an add-on in Firefox that can scale the text without changing everything else on the page.

Comment: Sorry - I'll add that it's a Windows app, not a web app - VB.NET, not asp

Comment: Try `AutoScaleMode=None`.

Comment: So I'm not sure if you aren't saying you've checked this (I'm not familliar with "Windows Easy Access setting", or "Make everything bigger"), but if you haven't, check the display "Scale and Layout" settings in the Windows Display settings. Some devices default to 100%, and others to 125% or even 150% DPI. DPI changes will sometimes only be effective if the application is exited and reopened, so it can sometimes be hard to judge the impact immediately.

Comment: $Frank Thomas I had not tried that setting yet and after a bit of experimentation I was able to replicate the issue at 115% scaling! Thank you for your help!! Now to solve the problem via programming, which I expect will be easier and more straightforward than finding it in the first place!